# Passing string as query params not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to pass a string value along with navigation from one component to other using queryparams.

```
Component1:
 stringdata = "Hello";
 this.router.navigate(['component2'], { queryParams:  stringdata });

Component2:

ngOnInit() {

  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params)
  })
}

Console output I get in component2 is:-
{
"0": "H",
"1": "E",
"2": "L",
"3": "L",
"4": "O",
}

In browser after navigation I can see 
domain.com/child20=H&1=E&2=L&3=L&4=O, why it is not passing as string!
```

Comment: Maybe **queryParams:  { stringdata }** ?

Comment: That is not a valid Query params. You may refer to [HTML5 URLs and the <base href>](https://angular.io/guide/router#html5-urls-and-the--base-href).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your string as query params like

```
this.router.navigate(['component2'], { queryParams:  { name: stringdata }});
```

And inside your component access it with

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params.name)
})
```

`queryParams` expect an object as argument.